# How can I redirect a random URL with a query string to the home page from .htaccess for SEO?

Tags: seo, htaccess, 301-redirect

I have been checking the progress of my site indexing in Google, for some bizarre reason best known to itself, there is a very random URL indexed against my domain which doesn't exist.

`http://www.example.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=35:is-it-possible-to-change-the-types-of-menu-entries&catid=31:general&Itemid=46`

Is there a way I can forward the URL and query string to the home page as a 301 in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

URL that google indexed ,should contain a part that doesn't exist in your site(or parameter in query string) !
Assume there is `GGGGGG` in that URL(and of course, that's Not in yours), so :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^\/(.*)GGGGGG(.*)$
RewriteRule   (.*)   http://www.footballadvisor.net [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply, not sure if I have done something wrong but this didnt work :(

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(.*)Itemid=46(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.footballadvisor.net [R=301,L]

Comment: @Richard G you should replace GGGGGG with something you that's wrong!